# In Visual Studio WinForms how do I allow the user to modify a particular value in a CSV text file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a 'Roster' application of sorts using Visual Studio WinForms, where the roster (list of people) is read from a (CSV) text file. There are 11 values per person in the text file. (Name, Description, etc). I have the application set up so that when the form loads, all of the Name values from this text file get loaded into a Listbox.

[image: screenshot]

Then, when the user clicks on the person in the Listbox, the labels on the form get updated to correspond with the values of the person selected. (Eg user clicks on 'Person 1" and the 'Description' label changes to the description of this particular person). This all works fine.

Now what I'm wanting to do is when the user clicks on the description label, an Inputbox is shown and the user is able to enter a new description. After the new description is added from the Inputbox, the description value of the person is then modified in the text file. I have no errors in the code I am using however the text file isn't changing to update with the new 'description'.

I am quite new to C# so hope this makes sense.

Many thanks!

```
private void lblDescription_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string input = Interaction.InputBox("Enter a new description", "Enter a value", personDescription, 0, 0);

     string idToFind = "Person 1";
     string newDescription = input;
     
    string line;
    while ((line = roster.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         string[] words = line.Split(',');

         for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
         {
             if (words[i] == idToFind)
             {
                 //words[i + 1] = newDescription;
                 words[i] = String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11}", personName,newDescription,personDrawValue, personInRingAbility, personMicSkills, personCharisma, personCondition, personAlignment, personWeight, personGender, personMorale, personRingStyle);
                 break;

             }
            File.WriteAllLines(roster2,words);
         }
     }
```

Comment: `string idToFind = "Person 1";` Should that be the list box's selected item?

Comment: Also, what are `roster` and `roster2`? Do they point to the same file?

Comment: Yes, the item the user selects in the listbox would become 'Person 1'. roster and roster2 point to the same file. roster is the StreamReader variable whereas roster2 is to write to the file. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this however, as stated, I am very new to C# haha.

Comment: Premature hint: You probably don't want to do `File.WriteAllLines...` inside the nested loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post talks about the loading and saving of the data ([Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/)) but that doesn't sound like the root issue causing trouble. Rather, there's a disconnect where you input some description text and it's not quite connecting back to the object that you're actually saving when you save. You mention being new to C# and if you haven't already heard the term [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) you soon will. As the name suggests it means that the UI control (like a text editor) and the data that is its target are wired to notify each other. Synchronized this way, it's impossible to have the kind of discrepancy you're seeing. The code below will wire changes in the `ListBox` to notify the other controls without having to write all that synchronization by hand.

[image: bindings]

---

The argument could be made that your app doesn't deal with a "file" at all. It deals with a **roster** of **persons** that can be abstracted as `BindingList<Person>` that will be the `DataSource` of `ListBox` if it's not aleady. You describe a person as a "set of eleven values" but we really want to nail this down.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Description("In Ring Ability")]
    public int InRingAbility { get; set; }

    [Description("Draw Value")]
    public int DrawValue { get; set; }
    public int Charisma { get; set; }
    public int Condition { get; set; }
    public string Alignment { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Morale { get; set; }

    [Description("Ring Style")]
    public string RingStyle { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Description("Mic Skills")]
    public int MicSkills { get; set; }
}
```

---

`ListBox` will manage a list of `Person` objects where `Name` is the property displayed in the list. As far as the text file, one way or another the aim here would be to turn it into a living breathing `List` in memory, and the reason I mentioned Json is for the ease (1 or 2 lines) with which this is done. The `ListBox` now shows the 5 names, and `listBox.SelectedValue` is a `Person` not a string.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();

    string _filePath = Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
        Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name,
        "roster.json"
        );
    BindingList<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if(!File.Exists(_filePath))
        {
            makeNewFile();
        }
        // Load the json (or other format) file into a List in memory
        var json = File.ReadAllText(_filePath);
        Persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BindingList<Person>>(json);

        listBox.DataSource = Persons;
        listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

---

Adding some bindings to your UI controls will make Selection Change in the list box automatically reflect in those controls.

```
    .
    .
    .
    labelName.DataBindings.Add("Text", listBox.DataSource, "Name");

    // Two-way binding for Description
    textBoxDescription.DataBindings.Add(
        "Text", 
        listBox.DataSource, 
        "Description",
        true, 
        DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    .
    .
    .
```

As a suggestion, the way I would personally do the Description editing is to turn the description "label" into an editable control with a double click.

[image: double-click to edit]

```
    .
    .
    .    
    textBoxDescription.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if(textBoxDescription.ReadOnly)
        {
            textBoxDescription.ReadOnly = false;
            textBoxDescription.BackColor = Color.White;
            textBoxDescription.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    };
    textBoxDescription.KeyDown += (sender, e) =>
    {
        switch(e.KeyData)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
                e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                if(!textBoxDescription.ReadOnly)
                {
                    textBoxDescription.ReadOnly = true;
                    textBoxDescription.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0,0,192);
                    textBoxDescription.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Persons, Formatting.Indented);
                    File.WriteAllText(_filePath, json);
                }
                break;
        }
    };
    .
    .
    .
```

When you reload the app, the changes will persist the way you intended.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/serialization-binding-intro.git)

Comment: Woah. You're awesome, thanks so much! I'm not sure I understand everything but I appreciate all the effort and help you put into this :-) Am trying to get this up and running however I get an error 'Could not find a part of the path' for the JSON file. I know absolutely nothing about these types of files. How would I go about creating one and what exactly should the contents be? (format, etc)

Comment: I copy and pasted everything from the post. As stated, I'm very new to this lol.

Comment: Not familiar at all.  When I attempt to do this I get an error message saying 'Get failed with a fatal error. repository 'github.com/IVSoftware/Serialization-binding-intro.git does not exist'.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint going into the OnLoad(). The path on your device will be in the `_filePath` variable if you hover your mouse over. I'd tell you what it was if I knew but it's unique to your machine because of the `Environment` parts of the path!

Comment: When you find it, check it out in Notepad. The `Json` serializer does all that formatting auto.

Comment: Sorry, amateur hour over here haha - have found the file. Thank you so much for all of your help, it is so appreciated! :-)

Comment: Done! Would upvote this x10 if I could :-)