# Filter binded datagrid so that it displays only items that have a particular value (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, class, data-binding, datagrid

So in my winforms project I have a datagrid that is binded to a 'Wrestler' class. This class has a number of different properties such as 'Name', 'Gender' ,'Title' (whether the person has a championship title or not), etc. This class gets its data from a JSON text file which contains all of the various 'Wrestlers' and their different attributes. The datagrid is set so that the only column visible is the 'Name' column. I also have a bunch of labels on the form that get updated to show the corresponding values of each 'Wrestler' object, whenever the user clicks on them in the datagrid.

This is all working fine however what I would like to do is have a 'Filter Champions' button where, when the user clicks it, only the 'wrestler' objects that DO NOT have the value "None" in their corresponding 'Title' property (those who DO hold a championship title) will be displayed in the DataGrid.

I consider myself a beginner in C# so I hope this makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

As I'm new to C# I have no idea where to start when it comes to filtering the datagrid in this manner. However, to give you an idea of what I have so far..

In the Form_Load event I have:

```
 var json = File.ReadAllText(_filePath);
 Wrestlers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BindingList<Wrestler>>(json);

var wrestlers = this.Wrestlers;
dataGridView1.DataSource = wrestlers;
```

In the datagrid _Cell Click event I have:

```
Wrestler selectedWrestler = (Wrestler)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.DataBoundItem;
lblName.Text = selectedWrestler.FullName;
lblTitle.Text = selectedWrestler.Title;
```

Comment: bind bound bound

Comment: I think you need to insert a BindingSource between DGV and DataSource. This can be filtered and sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a button and in on Click event of it, update the source of DataGrid and then refresh it. you can do this:

```
var newResult = wrestlers.Where(x=>x.Title != "None").ToList(); // Replace "None" with something that you Don't want Title Be.
// Or you can replace whole Condition after x=>x. for example (x=>x.Title == "championship")
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = wrestlers;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the attempt. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to make any difference at all :-(

Comment: I Looked at one of my WinForms projeccts, I think that this answer of mine is ok and working, maybe I didn't understand what you mean about "None". Remove Refresh line and Replace "None" with something that you don't want Title be. for example null. let me know if it helped. I'll edit my Answer

Comment: So, i simply changed dataGridView1.DataSource = wrestlers to dataGridView1.Datasource = newResult and it worked fine haha. Thanks alot!!

Comment: happy to hear that

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is load up a `BindingList<Wrestler>` similar to how you did for `ListView` in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77520144). But instead of binding this list of `AllWrestlers` directly to the `DataGridView`, make a second `BindingList<Wrestler>` called `FilteredWrestlers` and bind *it* to the `DataGridView`.

[image: unfiltered list]

When the `checkBoxFilterChampions` filter changes, run the `ApplyFilter()` method:

```cs
private void ApplyFilter()
{
    FilteredWrestlers.Clear();
    if(checkBoxFilterChampions.Checked) 
    {
        foreach (var wrestler in AllWrestlers.Where(_=>_.Titles.Any()))
        {
            FilteredWrestlers.Add(wrestler);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var wrestler in AllWrestlers)
        {
            FilteredWrestlers.Add(wrestler);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: filtered list]

---

**Wrestlers Class**

This class has been modified slightly to include a placeholder for the `Show Titles` column, and to hold an array of actual titles.

```cs
class Wrestler
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    // This will be a button column. Cell will be visible if wrestler has > 0 titles.
    public string? ShowTitles => null;

    public string[] Titles { get; set; } = new string[0];
    .
    .
    .
}
```

###### Instantiation example

```
new Wrestler
{
    Name = "MJF",
    Description = "First-ever World Middleweight Champion at the Battle Riot special.",
    Gender = "Male",
    Titles = new string[]{ "MLW World Middleweight Championship", "Rockstar Pro Tag Team Championship" }
},
```

---

**Handle the MainForm.Load event**

- Swap out the auto-generated `ShowTitles` column for a button column.
- Handle `CellPainting` event to show the button only if a wrestler has one or more titles
- Handle the button clicked to pop up a list of titles.

[image: pop up a list of titles]

```cs
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
#if false || REGEN
    File.Delete( _filePath );
#endif
    if (!File.Exists(_filePath))
    {
        makeNewFile();
    }
    var json = File.ReadAllText(_filePath);
    AllWrestlers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BindingList<Wrestler>>(json);

    // Here's the difference from the ListView answer
    dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    dataGridView.DataSource = FilteredWrestlers;
    DataGridViewColumn columnToSwap = dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Wrestler.ShowTitles)];
    int swapIndex =columnToSwap.Index;
    var buttonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
    {
        Name = columnToSwap.Name,
        HeaderText = columnToSwap.HeaderText,
    };
    buttonColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "Show All";
    // Style the buttons when painted.
    dataGridView.CellPainting += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if ((e.ColumnIndex != -1) && (e.RowIndex != -1))
        {
            if (dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewButtonCell buttonCell)
            {
                buttonCell.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                if (FilteredWrestlers[e.RowIndex].Titles.Any())
                {
                    buttonCell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 192);
                    buttonCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    // Show the titles when clicked
    dataGridView.CellContentClick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if ((e.RowIndex != -1) &&(dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Wrestler.ShowTitles)].Index == e.ColumnIndex))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, FilteredWrestlers[e.RowIndex].Titles));
        }
    };
    dataGridView.Columns.Remove(columnToSwap);
    dataGridView.Columns.Insert(swapIndex, buttonColumn);
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView.Columns)
    {
        col.HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font(dataGridView.Font.FontFamily, 8f);
        switch (col.Name)
        {
            case nameof(Wrestler.Name):
                col.ReadOnly = true;
                col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                break;
            case nameof(Wrestler.Description):
                // Allow editing for Description
                col.ReadOnly = false;
                col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
                break;
            default:
                col.ReadOnly = true;
                col.Width = 100;
                break;
        }
    }
    // If the checkbox changes, reapply the filter.
    checkBoxFilterChampions.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        ApplyFilter();
    };
    // If the underlying list of all wrestlers changes, reapply the filter.
    AllWrestlers.ListChanged += (sender, e) => ApplyFilter();
    // Initialize to FilteredWrestlers ~~ AllWrestlers
    ApplyFilter();
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This also worked really well and you have actually given me a few ideas for my project. Truly appreciate it all the help :-)

Comment: Glad as always to hear that things are moving forward. I meant to give you the [Repo](https://github.com/IVSoftware/filtered-data-grid-view.git) in case that helps at all. BTW, the justification for the "added complexity" is to be able to toggle not just this 'one' filter on and off, but also to be able to add other checkbox-buttons similar to `checkBoxFilterChampions` and process them all in `ApplyFilter()`. Also to make the binding "two-way" in case you wanted to edit `Description` like before.

Comment: Excellent thank you!!